# how to get linux version in Emacs

Tags: linux, emacs, version

I'm seeking for a way how to get linux version in Emacs Lisp, whatever the form is in string or number.
Please leave your code snippets if you have.

Thanks.

Comment: And what do you refer to as "linux version"?

Answer (score 1):

You can just call `uname -r` as a shell command.

```el
(defun my-linux-version ()
  "Return the linux version as a string."
  (shell-command-to-string "printf %s $(uname -r)"))
```

```
ELISP> (my-linux-version)
"4.4.0-96-generic"
```

---

*Edit:*

> trim the part -generic

```el
(defun my-linux-version ()
  "Return the linux version as a string."
  (let ((version (shell-command-to-string "printf %s $(uname -r)")))
    (replace-regexp-in-string "-generic$" "" version)))
```

Comment: I've tried to trim the part -generic xxx with regex but failed. Could you please also how to trim it??